# How do you create a 'premium' advertising network?

Tags: ads

I want to create a 'premium' ad network for a niche market, where I want to invite sites which are suitable for the ads.. is there a software or service which helps setting up an ad network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For software you can use [OpenX](http://www.openx.org/ad-server) as an ad server.

As for creating a premium network, you have a chicken and egg problem.  Sites won't sign up for exclusive ads unless you have good advertisers and can offer good rates.  Advertisers won't come until you have good sites.

I think what you are trying to build is something like [The DECK](http://decknetwork.net/) so if you haven't you might want to check out their service.